# Use Python extension with old version of Python

Tags: python

I want to use the cx_oracle module (http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/) in a project. It is currently built against Python 2.7. However I only have 2.6.6 installed on the machine, is it possible to rebuild a module against an older version of Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to build a fresh copy for your older Python version. `cx_oracle` comes with the source, all you need is the Oracle client libraries (which come with headers).

Answer (score 0):

[cx_oracle 5.1.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-oracle/files/5.1.1/) has a version for Python 2.6. You can download and use that.

You will be missing these [features](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releasenotes.html#version-5-1-2) in 5.1.1 by not using 5.1.2

- Added support for LONG_UNICODE which is a type used to handle long unicode strings. These are not explicitly supported in Oracle but can be used to bind to NCLOB, for example, without getting the error “unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested”.
- Set the row number in a cursor when executing PL/SQL blocks as requested by Robert Ritchie.
- Added support for setting the module, action and client_info attributes during connection so that logon triggers will see the supplied values, as requested by Rodney Barnett.